# Follow(acts_as_follower) a tag(acts_as_taggable_on)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on, acts-as-follower

I'm developing a Rails app where users can follow a `tag`. I'm using `acts_as_taggable` and `acts_as_follower`, but I don't know how to proceed.

**User model**:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

 acts_as_follower

end
```

**Posts model**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

But where should I put `acts_as_followable`?

Answer (score 0):

You should put `acts_as_followable` on anything you want users to be able to follow. In this case, I'm assuming you want users to be able to follow posts, so:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 acts_as_taggable_on :tags
 acts_as_followable
end
```

Keep in mind that this gem is completely unrelated to the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem. They do different things and do not interact by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
But what I want is the users to follow a tag, not a post.

Comment: @JuniorMiranda oh i missed that, sorry! one second.